# Restructure multidimensional array based on associative array key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have the following array:

```
$products = [
  [
    'id' => 21,
    'name' => 'Floral Dress',
    'params' => [
      'size' => 14,
      'price' => 23.99,
      'department' => 'Dresses'
    ]
  ],
  [
    'id' => 413,
    'name' => 'Maxi Skirt',
    'params' => [
      'size' => 10,
      'price' => 12.99,
      'department' => 'Skirts'
    ]
  ],
  [
    'id' => 78,
    'name' => 'A Line Prom Dress',
    'params' => [
      'size' => 10,
      'price' => 79.99,
      'department' => 'Dresses'
    ]
  ],
  [
    'id' => 212,
    'name' => 'Nude Block High Heels',
    'params' => [
      'size' => 6,
      'price' => 20.99,
      'department' => 'Shoes'
    ]
  ],
  [
    'id' => 54,
    'name' => 'Denim Trim Dress',
    'params' => [
      'size' => 8,
      'price' => 52.99,
      'department' => 'Dresses'
    ]
  ],
];
```

Unfortunately I cannot control how the array is built.

Instead I need to restructure the data so that the array is sorted by the `['params']['department']` key.

So ideally I would take the above and output it like so:

```
$products = [
  'Dresses' => [
    [
      'id' => 21,
      'name' => 'Floral Dress',
      'params' => [
        'size' => 14,
        'price' => 23.99
      ]
    ],
    [
      'id' => 78,
      'name' => 'A Line Prom Dress',
      'params' => [
        'size' => 10,
        'price' => 79.99
      ]
    ],
    [
      'id' => 54,
      'name' => 'Denim Trim Dress',
      'params' => [
        'size' => 8,
        'price' => 52.99
      ]
    ],
  ],
  'Skirts' => [
    [
      'id' => 413,
      'name' => 'Maxi Skirt',
      'params' => [
        'size' => 10,
        'price' => 12.99
      ]
    ],
  ],
  'Shoes' => [
    [
      'id' => 212,
      'name' => 'Nude Block High Heels',
      'params' => [
        'size' => 6,
        'price' => 20.99
      ]
    ],
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply iterate over all the products and populate a new associative array holding the departments, which are themselves arrays of corresponding products. See the comments in the code below.

```php
<?php
// same data as in the question, just in one line for better overview
$products = [['id' => 21,'name' => 'Floral Dress','params' => ['size' => 14,'price' => 23.99,'department' => 'Dresses']],['id' => 413,'name' => 'Maxi Skirt','params' => ['size' => 10,'price' => 12.99,'department' => 'Skirts']],['id' => 78,'name' => 'A Line Prom Dress','params' => ['size' => 10,'price' => 79.99,'department' => 'Dresses']],['id' => 212,'name' => 'Nude Block High Heels','params' => ['size' => 6,'price' => 20.99,'department' => 'Shoes']],['id' => 54,'name' => 'Denim Trim Dress','params' => ['size' => 8,'price' => 52.99,'department' => 'Dresses']]];

// initialize empty department array
$departments = array();

// iterate over all the products
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    // get this product's department
    $product_department = $product['params']['department'];
    // unset the department in the params array
    unset( $product['params']['department'] );

    // initialize this department as an empty array
    // if it doesn't exist yet
    if ( !isset( $departments[$product_department] ) ) {
        $departments[$product_department] = array();
    }
    
    // push this product in its corresponding department
    $departments[$product_department][] = $product;
}

var_dump( $departments );
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$groupedProducts = [];
foreach ($products as &$product) {
   $department = $product['params']['department'];
   unset($product['params']['department']);
   $groupedProducts[$department] = $product;
}

var_dump($groupedProducts);
```