# How to merge duplicates

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I want to merge the same records to:

```
Audi A3 / S3 / RS3
   8V / 8Y
Audi A4 / S4 / RS4
   B8 / B9
```

etc.

[But now it looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffX4M.png)

Here is my repository code:

```
public function cars(): array
{
    $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();

    $sql = 'select car.name as car, model.name as model from car join model on car.id = model.car_id';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // returns an array of arrays (i.e. a raw data set)
    return $stmt->executeQuery()->fetchAllAssociative();
}
```

twig:

```
{% for car in cars %}
{{ car.car }}
{{ car.model }}
{% endfor %}
```

controller:

```
public function index(ModelRepository $modelRepository): Response
{
   $cars = $modelRepository->cars();

    return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
        'cars' => $cars,
    ]);
}
```

Can you give me some tips how to get it to work properly?

Comment: Restructure the array in your controller before sending it to the view

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restructure multidimensional array based on associative array key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638487/restructure-multidimensional-array-based-on-associative-array-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to restructure the resulting data array, that is, prepare the desired data structure and pass the template to twig.

Controller method:

```
public function index(ModelRepository $modelRepository): Response
{ 
    $cars = [];
    foreach ($modelRepository->cars() as $item) {
        $cars[$item['car']][] = $item;
    } 
    return $this->render('index/index.html.twig', [
        'cars' => $cars,
    ]);
}
```

Twig:

```
{% for key, car in cars %}
    {{ key }}
    {% for item in car %}
        {{ item.model }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer. Thanks for help anyway. Just added my way.

Answer (score 2):

First change repository code from 'sql' to querybuilder:

```
public function cars()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->leftJoin('m.model', 'model')
        ->addSelect('model')
        ->addOrderBy('model.car', 'asc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

And then make some Twig changes:

```
{% for car in cars %}
  {{ car.name }}
    {% for model in car.model %}
      {{ model.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).